# How to select exact value in slider with a lot of values

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I have a slider with a lot of unique values (integers from 1to 10M).
The slider is about 5 - 10cm, depending on screen resolution, window size, etc.
It is almost impossible for the user to drag the slider to a specific desired value, lets say 10440.

I don't want to add a 'helper' control such as numeric up/down or textbox next to the slider, I want to just have a slider.

I have tried with a exponential slider, but didn't really succeed. How to solve this?

Comment: How about the [`IsSnapToTickEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider.issnaptotickenabled.aspx) property?

Comment: How many unique values do you have? You can't select more than one value per pixel with only a slider.

Comment: @Clemens that wont help because then I would need to have 10M ticks..
Raidri: 10M

Comment: If I were the user of your application, I'd expect an additional TextBox for numerical input of that exact value.

Comment: As said, I do not think this would be a desirable UI. Other than that, I am afraid it is not possible within the bounds of a normal slider. The user would be left to using the arrow keys to precisely move towards the desired value.

Comment: Right, you may set the `SmallChange` property to `1` so that arrow key input changes the slider value by +/-1. Maybe also `LargeChange` to 10 or 100, which would take effect on PageUp/Down input.